# What is the gray mark's meaning in Android Studio's Class simbol?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just came across this gray mark in the **Android Studio's Class** simbol and I'm wondering what is it for? *I really tried but I couldn't figure it out.*

Here is an example:

[image: Gray sign example]

*In advance, thanks!*

Comment: These are package-private classes

Comment: Pretty sure this mark means it's a `final` class (i.e. can't be sub-classed)

Comment: Oh yeah, it is a final class, indeed! Thanks!

Comment: just for help https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/symbols.html